# How to start additional PM2

Tags: javascript, python, pm2

[PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

So I have figured out a new might be a bug or something that I have done wrong.

I created a small script:

```
pm2 start test.py

>>>
import subprocess
import random
import time

print(f"hello {random.randint(1,500)}")

subprocess.Popen(f'pm2 start test.py --name {random.randint(1,500)}', shell=True).communicate()
time.sleep(3)
```

so basically what should happend is that when you run pm2 start test.py it should create a new pm2 script for test.py but with different name which I added as random.

What happens right now is that it doesn't star the Popen function if you run it through pm2 but if you run py test.py then its fine but if you start by doing pm2 start test.py then it wont add additional new script for test.py which logical it should?

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

If I run py test.py

```py
import random
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import time

while True:
    variable = random.randint(1, 500)
    print(f"hello {variable}")

    Popen(f"where python", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)

    time.sleep(3)

>>> hello 49
>>> C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
>>> C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

if I run pm2 start test.py same code:

```py
>>> hello 123
>>> hello 32
>>> hello 41
```